# YII2: bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission?

Tags: yii2, csrf

When I try swith on CSRF validation, I am getting this error. 
I have `Html::csrfMetaTags()` in main layout and it's working perfectly.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-frontend">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="QmcxU050NEIzD2AaDScBdxQqHAkFM04XCT9AFhZNQSlyIlISYy1yMg==">
```

I use activeForm and I checked POST Query and found that csrf information is sending correctly.

```
_csrf-frontend:Ukp1TC5KYUgaEBQIWwg4cCI7OCZEf1YYERJMfkIuAH84DD8ObQlTEA==
```

My config section:

```
'request' => [
    'cookieValidationKey' => 'LWCVTaYxV7aK6dqMWNKm1C7HMit6bJKa',
    'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
],
```

P.S. csrf-token data in meta name and data in post query is different, is this okay or not?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser or does your yii app have session enabled? What happens if you add "'enableCookieValidation' => true," in your request settings?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're sending the parameters inside each form?

Inside your form you have to add a hidden parameter like this:

```
echo  Html::hiddenInput(
   Yii::$app->request->csrfParam,
   Yii::$app->request->csrfToken
);
```

So each request receives the CSRF data,I haven't done at layout level.

Comment: I use ActiveForm to Generating Html code. And i checked html code and I found hidden fields contain csrfToken and csrfParam data. I checked data in sended post query also. There is same - everything is ok